# What does key "M" mean in Emacs?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

I am totally new to Emacs and am reading [this tutorial](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/tour/), and it mentions:

```
M-f    Forward one word
```

Which key is `M`?

As such pressing M followed by f types `Mf` and pressing them together also types some combination of M and f.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`M-` is `meta`, which is an old X11 extended shift key designation.  In modern systems it's *usually* the `Alt` key.  You can also press `Esc` followed by the other keys in the sequence (here, `Esc f`).

You mostly won't see them on modern machines, but there are other extended shifts such as `S-` (`super`; you may see this if you press the `Windows` key) and `H-` (hyper).

Comment: [`Ctrl-x M-c M-butterfly`](http://xkcd.com/378/)